Can someone spend native Ethereum from a signer's address using just a signature?
I'm exploring Ethereum's cryptographic features and wondering if there’s a way for someone to use a signature to spend native Ethereum (ETH) from the signer's address without directly requiring the signer's involvement in sending the transaction.
Is it possible to provide a signature that authorizes another party to transfer ETH from the signer's account? If so, how would this mechanism work, and what are the potential risks or limitations involved?
I understand that there are mechanisms like ERC20 approvals for tokens, but I’m specifically interested in native ETH. Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Hi there @syed-asad-kazmi , maybe you know the answer ?

I’ve just answered.

I don’t think that it’s possible because transferring of native token (i.e., ETH in case of Ethereum network) is not associated with any function call, as it does not involve any contract interaction.
But, if you use an intermediate smart contract wallet such as a Gnosis Safe or a custom contract that holds the ETH. The signer would authorize transfers from this contract via signed messages. This setup allows another party to send ETH on behalf of the user, but ETH would need to be deposited into the contract first.
So, native ETH itself cannot be transferred directly through a signature without involving the signer’s wallet in some way.
